# Running .exe file within a C++ code

Tags: c++, exe

I downloaded an .exe file named primesum.exe from https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesum/releases/download/v1.1-256-bit/primesum-1.1-256-win64.zip
It can be executed by "primesum 1e10" to get sum of all prime numbers up to 1e10. I want to use this .exe file in a C++ program, where this .exe file will be accessed multiple times with different arguments. Is it possible to do so? I tried this.

EDIT: Now I can execute the file from the C++ code. Is there a way to get the output as a string. I need it for further use in the code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long int n = (long long int)1e10;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << n;
    string command = "primesum " + ss.str();
    FILE *fp = popen(command.c_str(), "w");
    char res[512];
    fgets(res, 512, fp);
    string ans = string(res);
    cout << "answer = " << ans << "\n";
    fclose (fp);
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet? Say I want to get the sum for n=10^10, how should I use the popen function?

Comment: Now I can run the .exe file by taking input from a C++ code, but can't get the output as a string. It prints the result in the terminal, but I need that value for further use in the code. Can I do that? I read quite a few stack overflow answers, but they are nor working. Any help? I shall modify my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it :)

Comment: Don't call `fclose(fp)` and `pclose(fp)` - you should only be calling `pclose(fp)`.